# Problem with heredoc statement

Tags: php

I am trying to replace the HTML code with a heredoc statement. However, I am getting a parse error in the last line.I am sure that I have not left any leading space or indentation on the heredoc closing tag line.Following is **a part of** the code:

```
$table = <<<ENDHTML
    <div style="text-align:center;">
    <table border="0.5" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" style="width:50%; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;">
    <tr>
    <th>Show I.D</th>
    <th>Show Name</th>
    </tr>
    ENDHTML;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
            extract($row);
            $table .= <<<ENDHTML
            <tr>
                <td>$showid2 </td>
                <td>$showname2</td>
            </tr>
    ENDHTML;        
    }
    $table .= <<<ENDHTML
    </table>
    <p><$num_shows Shows</p>
    </div>
    ENDHTML; 
    echo $table;
    ?>
```

Where is the problem?
I have a related question in addition to above. As a coding practice, is it better to use PHP code throughout or is it better to use a heredoc syntax. I mean, while in PHP mode, the script bounces back and forth between the HTML and PHP code. 
So, which is the preferred method?

Comment: that code needs some pre-tags, hard to tell which is the last line... :)

Comment: Honestly for this format, you'd probably run into a lot less problems if you uses single quotes. You would still get all the newlines and tab spaces, and wouldn't run into the problems with HEREDOC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guys, finally I succeeded in getting the parse error out of my way (phew!!). I just rewrote the code and it worked. Here is the code:

```
$table = <<<ABC
  <div style="text-align:center;">
  <table border="0.5" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" style="width:50%; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;">
  <tr>
  <th>Show I.D</th>
  <th>Show Name</th>
  <th>Show Genre</th>
  </tr>
ABC;
  while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
  {
      extract($row);
$table .= <<<ABC
      <tr>
      <td>$showid2 </td>
      <td>$showname2</td>
      <td>$showtype2_label</td>
      </tr>
ABC;
  }
$table .= <<<ABC
  </table>
  <p>$num_shows Shows</p>
  </div>
ABC;

echo $table;
```

Answer (score 6):

From the [PHP manual about the Heredoc syntax](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc):

> The closing identifier ***must*** begin in the first column of the line.

And a little later in the nice red *Warning* box:

> It is very important to note that the line with the closing identifier must contain no other characters, except ***possibly*** a semicolon (;). That means especially that the identifier ***may not be indented***, and there may not be any spaces or tabs before or after the semicolon.

So you need to write the code like this to comply with the syntax specification:

```
$table = <<<ENDHTML
    <div style="text-align:center;">
    <table border="0.5" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" style="width:50%; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;">
    <tr>
    <th>Show I.D</th>
    <th>Show Name</th>
    </tr>
ENDHTML;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
                extract($row);
                $table .= <<<ENDHTML
                <tr>
                        <td>$showid2 </td>
                        <td>$showname2</td>
                </tr>
ENDHTML;
    }
    $table .= <<<ENDHTML
    </table>
    <p><$num_shows Shows</p>
    </div>
ENDHTML;
    echo $table;
```

It’s up to you if you really want to use that.

Comment: I tried nearly everything but that parse code is just not bidding me goodbye. I think it's better if I bid goodbye to heredoc

Answer (score 2):

If this code is exactly what you are using, then there are a number of spaces down the left hand side with the exception of the first $table = <<<ENDHTML line. The ending heredoc needs to be exactly left-aligned with no spaces, tabs or other characters to the left of it.

Comment: Everything is perfectly on the left side in my code editor. It's only showing the left spaces here.God..I will tear my hairs apart :(

Comment: Can you reduce the code to a smaller test case? I.e. remove heredocs until you no longer receive the error?

Comment: Actually I have run the code without heredoc suntax i.e by using HTML with PHP code..that runs pretty well..I just wanted to try the heredoc syntax..and then came the problem :(

Answer (score 1):

`<p><$num_shows Shows</p>`

Is that an extraneous '<' character before `$num_shows`?

Comment: I just added here by mistake. Although it's not present in the original code.

Comment: And even if it was there, it couldn't generate a parse error, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't this pose a problem?

> ```
> </tr>
> ENDHTML;
> ```

You should probably:

> ENDHTML;

**Edit:**
Formatting failed ... and Richy C. said the same in the meantime :( I just meant to show that the first `ENDHTML;`has whitespace in front of it.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: changed to ob and back and now the loop works for me ...

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    extract($row);
    $table .= <<< ENDHTML
    <tr>
        <td>$showid2</td>
        <td>$showname2</td>
    </tr>
ENDHTML;
}
```