# In which bizarre scenario can multiline strings fail to work?

Tags: php

For some reason I've made some change either in whitespace somewhere, that it makes it fail.

```
public function test() {
    $multiLineSring = <<<EOD
    this awesome person
    has become something else
    entirely
    EOD;
}
```

I get the following error:

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in

Comment: What is your PHP version?  Something below PHP7.3? https://3v4l.org/XjaJQ

Comment: I’ve seen that specific message when incorrectly using variables inside heredoc strings: https://3v4l.org/pfBvF#v7.0.0

Comment: @mickmackusa yes

Comment: @ChrisHaas No variables.

Comment: Pages linked to the canoncial that I hammered with (but ADyson unhammered it): [PHP: Using Proper Indentation with Heredocs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4068556/2943403) and [Problem with heredoc statement](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1222638/2943403) and [I used heredoc syntax to cover my string. But It displays error. Below is my code:](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6342415/2943403) and [Issue with heredoc and PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27108744/2943403) and [PHP Heredoc string rules](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7581315/2943403)

Comment: and [php formatting string EOD](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6071580/2943403) and ["syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE)" while using HEREDOC syntax in PHP7.2, but PHP7.4 is fine](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65197717/2943403)

Comment: @JohnConde We have been informally asked to avoid closing dupes with laundry-list canonicals such as https://stackoverflow.com/a/18092288/2943403 but I can appreciate that that page does explicitly say what was wrong.  See [Rule proposal: Duplicate closure to roll-up questions is no longer allowed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/427530/2943403) More concerningly, I don't understand why ADyson unhammered my canonical which was very appropriate and has many signposts already.

Comment: @mickmackusa Thank you for making me aware. I am not around much anymore so I missed that.